# what is "novalidate" attribute really about?

Tags: html

I don't really get the concept of *novalidate* attribute,looking at its usage on websites it says:
**When present,it specifies that the form-data (input) should not be validated when submitted.**, but what does that really mean?, can someone please explaine the meaning of Data-validation?Thanks.

Comment: What is your misunderstanding? Fields with that attribute should not be validated.

Comment: I don't know what being validated means and that  what my real question is

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/novalidate

Comment: Thank you Evan!that helped.